# Can the data model be used without pivot tables, e.g. to replace vlookup in a simple table?

Tags: excel

I find the excel data model useful. But having built a data model, how can I look up values? It seems to be useful for pivot tables, I can add fields from related tables. But I want to add a column to my 'normal' table with a 'looked-up' value.

E.g. (hopefully unnecessary example) table `people` has columns `id` and `name`. Table `comments` has columns `comment` and `people_id`. I told excel that `people_id` is a foreign key to `id` in table `people`. I now want to display the `comments` table with the actual names as a new column, not just the id. How can I do this? Add a new table based on a query?

I know this is possible using functions like vlookup, but I am wondering if the data model can help. Google does not seem to return anybody having this problem, most people are content with vlookup or pivot tables.

Powerpivot has a function that would be perfect, called `RELATED`.

Comment: I don't completely follow your question, but if you want to simulate database functionality in Excel, then pivot tables are one way to do this.

Comment: I know. But I wonder if this 'database-simulation-bolt-on' can be used _without_ pivot tables, like the RELATED function.

Comment: Depending on your complexity, you can probably do this with pure Excel, but keep in mind that whatever you do will have to maintained, passed on to others, etc.  Choose the path of least resistance.

Comment: Yes, but in the right situation the data model can lead to very elegant solutions. If this is possible it will be a lot simpler than endless vlookups.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer: You can use Excel's CUBE functions to access POWERPIVOT data.
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Cube-functions-reference-2378132b-d3f2-4af1-896d-48a9ee840eb2?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

and Jon Acamporas 
https://www.excelcampus.com/cubevalue-formulas/